# rest api with pagination in zf2

Tags: php, rest, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I am running a functionality of listing the cities with the rest api url, http://localhost/cities, to get the result set as:

```
[
  {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "totalRecords": 1220,
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New York"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Washington"
      }
      .....
    ]
   }
]
```

and this is my code:

Module Config:

```
'listcities' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/cities',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'City\Controller\City',
                        'action' => 'listCities',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

City Controller:

```
public function listCitiesAction() {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");

        $response = array();

        $cities = $this->libraryService->listCities();
        if (isset($cities) && count($cities) > 0) {
            $response[] = $this->getCityResponse($cities);
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'FAILURE';
            $response['errorCode'] = 578;
            $response['errorMessage'] = "No cities found";
        }
        return new JsonModel($response);
    }

private function getCityResponse($cities) {
        $citiesArray = array();
        $response = array();
        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $citiesArray[] = ['id' => $city->getId(),
                'name' => $city->getName()
            ];
        }
        $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
        $response['totalRecords'] = count($citiesArray);
        $response['cities'] = $citiesArray;

        return $response;
    }
```

The above code is from the controller, where the service is called and from the service, repository model is called to get the list of cities. So hereby i used the Doctrine2 ORM, to list the cities. My question how can i insert the pagination script in the Doctrine2 ORM.

City Reposity:

```
public function findAll() {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository('Library\Entity\City')
                ->findBy(array('active' => true));
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the Paginator from Doctrine? see here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Comment: It seems to be for non-rest calls, that is in viewModel

Comment: I don't understand how this should be related to Rest? What did you do far to extend your controller to get the information for start and limit which you will need in any way?